# Finite existence $\int _A (y^2+(z-1)^2+x^2)^{\alpha} dx dy dz$

Tags: real-analysis

$A=\{(x,y,z) \in R^3: x^2+y^2+z^2\le4;x^2+y^2+z^2\le 4z\}$

Can i use spherical coordinates$x=\rho \sin\theta \cos \phi,x=\rho \sin\theta \sin \phi,z=1+\rho \cos\theta$?

Comment: Isn't that the intersection of a cone, with vertex in the origin, and a sphere? You probably want to split the integral over two sets and use spherical coordinates on one, and cylindrical on the other.

Comment: There are two spheres and, given the symmetry around the $z$ axis$ I think that it's better to use cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: I have found integrability near 0 for $\alpha>-1$